# Combinding armature and sphere animation

Tags: export, gltf, three.js

The case is that im working on combining two animations (the light settings of a sphere and rotation of an armature) from an exported gltf 3d model with its corresponding animations in a react project using threejs (react-three/drei) When i inspect the 3d model in the browsers inspector tool only the armature animation strips are available, how come the animation strips from the sphere not be included or at least accessible after export?

video of the animations run in blender
https://vimeo.com/848725778?share=copy

[image: the object animations after being exported from blender]

[image: export settings]

Comment: What do you mean by "the light settings of a sphere" ? If you animated shaders, I'm not sure shader animations are supported.

Comment: animation of light shaders is the right term. does there exist any method to get around this restriction, combining the two animations in blender before export or anything like that?

Comment: I checked the manual, it is indeed not supported: [glTF 2.0 — Blender Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.80/addons/io_scene_gltf2.html#:~:text=Animation%20of%20other%20properties%2C%20like%20lights%20or%20materials%2C%20will%20be%20ignored.)

Comment: Maybe you can add a bone that isn't influencing anything, copy your shader's animation keys to any of the bone's transform channels, export as is, then maybe in treejs you have a system to somehow extract that data and use it on the shader there.

Comment: thx for the useful info!